# How to change input to scanner

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a bit stuck here. Currently I am doing a project for school. I recently found out that the code was supposed to read from a file and not from user input. Is there any way I would be able to change my process? The file i would need it to read is QuarterlyEmployeeData.txt
Here is my main class:

MonthlyPayroll.java

```
import java.util.*;

class MonthlyPayrollDriver
{
    private static final int WORKFORCE_SIZE = 3;
    private static Scanner inputScan;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        // Set up array of employees
        // Note the objects in the array could be in subclasses of Employee
        Employee[] employeeList = new Employee[WORKFORCE_SIZE];

        inputScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int empNum = 0; empNum < WORKFORCE_SIZE; empNum++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter employee first name and last name: ");
            String first = inputScan.next();
            String last = inputScan.next();
            System.out.print("\nPlease determind the Status code (F for full-time, P for part time, and I for intern) ");
            char response = inputScan.next().charAt(0);
            {

            if (response == 'f' || response == 'F')
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease determind the Status Code (S for salaried or H for hourly) ");
                {
                    char response1 = inputScan.next().charAt(0);
                    if (response1 == 'h' || response1 == 'H')
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nEnter hourly rate: ");
                        double hourlyRate = inputScan.nextDouble();
                        System.out.print("\nEnter hours worked last Month: ");
                        inputScan.nextDouble();
                        employeeList[empNum] = new HourlyEmployee(last,first,hourlyRate);
                    }
                    char response2 = inputScan.next().charAt(0);
                    if (response2 == 's' || response2 == 'S')
                    {
                        System.out.print("Enter annual salary: ");
                        double annualPay = inputScan.nextDouble();
                        employeeList[empNum] = new SalariedEmployee(last,first,annualPay);
                    }
                }

            }

            if (response == 'p' || response == 'P') 
            {
                System.out.print("\nEnter hourly rate: ");
                double hourlyRate = inputScan.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("\nEnter hours worked last month: ");
                inputScan.nextDouble();
                employeeList[empNum] = new HourlyEmployee(last, first,
                        hourlyRate);

            }

            if (response == 'i' || response == 'I')
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease determind the Status Code (H for hourly or U for unpaid.) ");
                {
                    char response1 = inputScan.next().charAt(0);
                    if (response1 == 'H' || response1 == 'h') 
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nEnter hourly rate: ");
                        double hourlyRate = inputScan.nextDouble();
                        System.out.print("\nEnter hours worked last month: ");
                        inputScan.nextDouble();
                        employeeList[empNum] = new HourlyEmployee(last, first,
                                hourlyRate);
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        employeeList[empNum] = new HourlyEmployee(last,first,0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

        System.out.println("\n\nMonthly Payroll\n");
        for(int j = 0; j < WORKFORCE_SIZE; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(employeeList[j]);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, change

```
inputScan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to

```
inputScan = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
```

where `filePath` is the path to the `File` you need to read. The [`Scanner(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) javadoc says,

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified file.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't pick up the file. Also what if its located in a different place at different computers

Answer (score 1):

This is what makes your program read from the standard input, which is console by default:

```
inputScan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can change this in two ways:

- [Redirect the standard input of your program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) to a file using OS-specific syntax, or
- Create a scanner that reads from a file.

The first option is done like this:

```
java MonthlyPayrollDriver <my_input_file.txt
```

The second option is done like this:

```
File file = new File("my_input_file.txt");
inputScan = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: For the first option what do I change to make it work?

Comment: @TheBeginning You do not need to change anything to make the first option work, not even a recompile.

Comment: @TheBeginning What is happening when you run it like that? Do you get errors? Do you get some output? Try running this in a debugger, step through your code, and see what is going on.

Comment: I'm trying the second method because I realized I would be using that. Now I'm "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MonthlyPayrollDriver.main(MonthlyPayrollDriver.java:29)